# Why Mockito.when(...).thenThrow(...) throw directly an error

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following code :

```
@Mock
private B b;

@InjectMocks
private A a;

@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void test() {
    when(b.doSomething())
        .thenThrow(IOException.class);

    a.doSomethingWithB();
}

public class A {
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    public a(B b) {
        this.b = b
    }

    public boolean doSomethingWithB() {
        b.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Actually, this test not working correctly, when I debug it, the `thenThrow` line return the `IOException`and by the fact, it never go on `a.doSomethingWithB()`.

My Mockito version is 2.19.1.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem instead of vaguely describing your code.

Comment: You haven't posted the definition of class B.

Comment: Oh, sorry, @JBNizet.  I know.  It's been a long day :-)  I, of course, was thinking of the (arguably superior) static doThrow method.

Comment: Wouldn't the execution of statements in the normal flow stop the moment you throw the execution ?

Answer (score 2):

The method `B#doSomething()` cannot throw an IOException because it is not part of its signature. That is the reason why Mockito does not allow you to do `thenThrow(IOException.class)`.

You can see this if you look at the stacktrace of the failing test:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.io.IOException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException>

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluateSafely(JUnitRule.java:52)
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    ....
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
```

Comment: So what should (s)he put instead of `IOException`, except `Exception`? Something more accurate.

Comment: Whatever type of exception they want to test for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: your mocked object `b` is not getting injected into object `a`. For injecting that mocked object `b` into `a` in that test class, you need to annotate your test class with either of them `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `Mockito.initMocks(this)`.

Comment: you must use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or Mockito.initMocks(this) to initialise mocks and inject them on ur test class.

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution is to use:

`doThrow(IOException.class).when(b).doSomething();`

instead of:

`when().thenThrow`

(Checked this with Mockito `1.10.19` and it works, but with `2.19.0` it doesn't work)